# React-router-dom and Redux not rerendered the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

EDIT : I found the solution, I forget `switch` component in my `routes.js`

I have created a route like that : `/post/:id`

my `routes.js` look like :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Posts from "./components/Posts";
import Post from "./components/Post";
class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
            <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

At my `/`route I listed all my `posts`, and when I click on one of them I update the url `http://localhost:3000/post/1` for example.

*PS : I tried to use `withRouter` function as it says in the official document of react-router, but this case not work in my case.*

The file in question is `post.js` it look like :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { active_post } from "../actions/index";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Post extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.active_post(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.post);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Detail d'un post</h1>
        <p>{this.props.match.params.id}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    post: state.activePost
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ active_post }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

So for example, if I enter manually in the URL bar `http://localhost:3000/post/3` for example I have the component and the `console.log()` with the post when I need.

So please if you have a solution for this case I take this. 
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding a `Switch` from react-router-dom around your routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
            <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Don't forget to include the Switch module from react-router-dom in your component.

`import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Just before your answer I edited my thread... 
But I don't understand why we need to use switch component, you can explain please ?

Comment: I just looked at my own project and saw that I was using the `<Switch>` element ;). But according to the react-router-dom documentation, Switch makes sure to only render the first `<Route>` that matches your url. To read more about react-router-dom Switch check out the following link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch. Just to make sure, your code works when adding the `<Switch>`?